# git pull без вопроса о пароле

Tags: git, github

Есть закрытый репозиторий. Чтобы сделать pull нужно ввести пароль. Все как обычно, вначале `git pull origin master`, а потом запрос пароля от меня.

Так вот, как вместить в одну строчку с `git pull origin master` ввод пароля, чтобы он у меня потом не запрашивался ?

Comment: git config --global credential.helper wincred

Comment: Это если у вас Windows

Comment: У меня Linux...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если используете **Windows**, то поможет команда:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

В случае **Linux**:

```
git config credential.helper store
git push
```

После требуется указать *username* и *пароль* и все.

Также можете время жизни кэша следующим способом:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 3600
```

Если хотите очистить кэш вручную, то воспользуйтесь командой:

```
git credential-cache exit
```

Answer (score 2):

Может просто публичный ключ настроить? Тогда никаких паролей не надо.